# HTML div alignment using margins

Tags: html, css

I am aligning the divs by using their margin properties

The Css goes like this

```
#top
{
    width:1000;
    height:150;
}

#left
{
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top : 150;
    width:200;
    height:500;
}

#right
{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:200;
    margin-top:150;
}
```

I want the top div to be at the top of the page, the left div towards the left and right div towards the right. But there is something seriously wrong here. The right div is way below the left div.

Comment: where you have not included `px` for values

Comment: Does that make a differe?

Comment: yes very big difference

Answer (score 0):

For the right and left `div`s use: `float:left;`

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7fjk3wxs/

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #000;     
}

#top
{
    width:100%;
    height:150;
}

#left
{
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    width: 20%;
}

#right
{
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    width: 79%;
}
```

Comment: I just did and the right div goes all the way over to the extreme right.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use float property:

```
#left
{
    float:left;
    margin-top : 150px;   
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
}

#right
{

    float:right;
    margin-top:150px;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w810reb1/)